# Multiple overlays, right-click save only save one

Tags: javascript, save, overlay, screenshot, appendchild

Newbie here, experimenting. I'm trying to create in html/javascript a single image by stacking randomly selected layers (see code below). However, when I right-click the image it only saves the top layer, not all layers. How do I fix this (a button would be possible if it does not use any libraries -same goes for screenshots)?

Many thanks in advance!

Skipper

```
//html
<div><div id="layers"></div>

<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>

// script

//create and attach layer1 to body;
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.alt = "Layer1";
            img.src = layer1_array[getRandomInt(0,3)];
            img.setAttribute("id","myImg");
            img.style.decoding = "async";
            document.getElementById("layers").appendChild(img);


//create and attach layer1 to body;
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.alt = "Layer2";
            img.src = layer2_array[getRandomInt(0,3)];
            img.setAttribute("id","myImg");
            img.style.decoding = "async";
            document.getElementById("layers").appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const arrayImage = ["./img/img1.png", "./img/img2.png", "./img/img3.png"];

    const innerImage = (index) => {
        const image = new Image(canvas.width, canvas.height);
        image.addEventListener("load", () => {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        });
        image.src = arrayImage[index];
    };
    innerImage(0);
    innerImage(2);
    innerImage(1);


</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
(async () => {
    innerImage(0);
    innerImage(1);
    innerImage(2);
})()
```

Comment: I think you need to do an async function

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the issue still persists. I've also tried adding 
<< image.style.decoding = "async";>> but that did not seem to make any difference

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please refrain from just posting lines of code and consider adding a short explanation through comments

Comment: Hi and apologies. I have edited the code to reflect your suggestion of adding an async function. I think it still needs to be approved by a community member to become visible. Unfortunately, the problem of layers stacking out of order still persists every 10 reloads on average (seemingly random). So, I was thinking perhaps the issue is also with the initial layers (l1, l2). Could I somehow make sure they're all loaded before continuing? Thanks for all your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: I should add that I have added both the async function and the await command. There is some improvement but the issue is still present. Thanks!